# Synchronize server directory with local directory FileZilla?

Tags: ftp, web-hosting

I have uploaded a website online and had to make some hotfixes directly on the server directories, but now there is a discrepancy between my local directory and the server directory.

I tried to navigate FileZilla settings to check if there is a way to synchronize the files between the server dir and local dir (or vise versa) but could not get to a way this could be done with FileZilla.

Is there a workaround to achieve this with FileZilla without any other extensions/plugins? What could be the best way to do this knowing that I'm on windows machine?

Comment: Anyway, see [FileZilla - How to synchronize two-way (newest file wins)?](http://superuser.com/q/935353/213663)

Comment: Ok noted, thanks for your answer @MartinPrikryl, beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't meet your specific requirements of the answer having to be FileZilla, but if you don't get such an answer, I'd recommend using WinSCP to do this.  I think some of its FTP functionality is actually based on FileZilla, and it has a powerful sync feature that has preview functionality that will let you see what's going to happen before it does the sync, and you can choose to sync or not sync individual files from that preview if you want to customize the operation further.  You can read more about its sync at https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full, though it's pretty self-explanatory.  You access it from the Commands -> Synchronize menu option.